# How to Evaluate arithmetic expression using j2me?

Tags: java-me

I send formula information in the excel file to j2me application with data in those cells.Now, i want to read the formula information ie, expression, and then evaluate the expression.

for example : i have 3 Cells in my excel sheet.

```
Cell A1 = 1
Cell B1 = 2
Cell C1=(A1+B1)
```

now i will send Cell Address and cell Value and formula.The J2me Application first read the formula and then evaluate the expression and display it...This is simple expression sometimes, the expression more complex.

any built in postfix,infix algorithms is available for evaluating math expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no any other api for doing that.We have to manually write the code in j2me side.

Comment: I bet someone should write one!

Comment: I'll be writing one now

Comment: @NiteshVerma:Thanks a lot...Good initiative... All the very best :-) Please let me know once done